# Java Hibernate show org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: User

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I'm trying to make my first Hibernate project. I've written the code for inserting data into table. It shows `unknown entry : User` at `session.save()`.

I've also added mapping for class `User`.

hibernate.db

```
public class hibernatedb {
    private SessionFactory factory;
    public hibernatedb() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        Metadata meta = new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();
        factory = meta.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();  
    }
    public void insert(int id,String name){
        Session session=factory.openSession();
        Transaction tr=session.beginTransaction();
        User u=new User();
        u.setId(id);
        u.setName(name);
        try {
            session.save(u);
            tr.commit();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        session.close();
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

User.java

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 5.3//EN"  
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-5.3.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>  
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1</property>  
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>  
        <property name="connection.password"></property>  
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>  
        <mapping class="User"/>  
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

stack trace:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: User
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:620)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1636)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:683)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at hibernatedb.insert(hibernatedb.java:25)
    at MyServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:22)
    at MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:26)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Comment: Look into this line: `<mapping class="User" />`, it looks like the issue is there since it didn't "register" your `User` entity. Are you using any package name for `User`? On the other hand, Hibernate entities must conform to some standards.

Comment: Replace the mapping with `<property name="packagesToScan">
   <list>
    <value>path.to.package</value>
   </list>
  </property>`. The mapping of the class itself looks fine. If at all you can also speficy how the `@GeneratedValue` works (generationType)

Comment: I have also tried @generatedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) but nothing changed.@XtremeBaumer